# How to delete Navigation Link > symbol in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

How to delete Navigation Link > symbol in SwiftUI?

---

[image]

**Navigation code**

```
NavigationView{
    List{
        ForEach(messages) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: MessageDetailView()){
                ChatRowView(chat: item)
                .padding(.vertical,3)
            }
           
        }
     
  
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chevron image of link is injected by `List` for automatically detected `NavigationLink`. This is default behavior of `List`.

The possible solution is to replace `NavigationLink` inside `List` with `Button` and activate `NavigationLink` programmatically.

Here is a demo of approach. Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

[image: demo]

```
struct Message: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let messages = [Message(id: "1"), Message(id: "2"), Message(id: "3")]
    @State private var tappedItem: Message?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(messages) { item in
                    Button(action: { tappedItem = item }) {   // << activate !!
                        Text("Message \(item.id)")
                            .padding(.vertical,3)
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("MessageDetailView \(tappedItem?.id ?? "")"),
                    isActive: Binding(
                        get: { tappedItem != nil },         // << handle !!
                        set: { _,_ in tappedItem = nil }
                    )){
                    EmptyView()
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not use List in this case:

---

### [image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
            
            VStack {
                
                ForEach(0..<10) { item in
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("some text here!")){
                        
                        HStack { Text("Link " + item.description); Spacer() }.padding(.horizontal)
                        
                    }
                    
                    Divider()
                    
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Hello World!")
            
        }
    }
}
```