# swiftui how to remove chevron on navigation link list in 2023?

Tags: swiftui, foreach, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

Is there a cleaner solution different by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904299/how-to-delete-navigation-link-symbol-in-swiftui)  and [this answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/701449)to remove those chevrons on lists? Maybe today apple improved it (even not using navigationStack) the kind of issue.

I know there is same question, but is relatively a bit old, and I'm wondering if there is a better solution today, still not using navigation stack. the first given solution seems to be a bit slow respect standard code, and a bit too verbose.

my starting code

```
import SwiftUI

struct FakeCar: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let name: String
}


struct DevelopingView: View {

    let test: [FakeCar] = [
        FakeCar(name: "car 1"),
        FakeCar(name: "car 2")
    ]

    @State private var tappedItem: FakeCar?

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
                //standard code with chevron, I do not want it.
                Section (header: Text("Base")) {
                    ForEach(test) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("destination: \(item.name)") ) {
                            Text(item.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                //solution from apple site, but adding vstack elements are not "centered" vertically due to navigation link
                //✅ SOLUTION this version is upgraded by me, I needed to remove the default chevron, adding VStack with its options, and opacity and frame to empty navigtionLink
                Section (header: Text("test 1 - ✅ solution")) {
                    ForEach(test) { item in
                        ZStack {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                                NavigationLink(destination: Text("destination: \(item.name)")) { EmptyView() }
                                    .opacity(0.0)
                                    .frame(height:0)
                                Text(item.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Section (header: Text("test 1.1 - ✅✅ better solution")) {
                    ForEach(test, id: \.self) { item in
                        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("destination: \(item.name)")) {
                                EmptyView()
                            }
                            .opacity(0)
                            Text(item.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                //another solution i tested, but elements are "centered" and do not know how to adjust it
                Section (header: Text("test 2")) {
                    ForEach(test, id: \.self) { item in
                        ZStack {
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("destination: \(item.name)")) {
                                EmptyView()
                            }
                            .opacity(0)
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                            Text(item.name)
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        //solution found on stack, works, but is a bit verbose and unclear
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(test) { item in
                    Button(action: { tappedItem = item }) {   // << activate !!
                        Text("Select: \(item.name)")
                            .padding(.vertical,3)
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("MessageDetailView \(tappedItem?.name ?? "N/D")"),
                               isActive: Binding(
                                get: { tappedItem != nil },         // << handle !!
                                set: { _,_ in tappedItem = nil }
                               )){
                                   EmptyView()
                               }
            )
        }
    }
}




//gives Identifiable tho stringgs
extension String: Identifiable {
    public typealias ID = Int
    public var id: Int {
        return hash
    }
}
```

SOLUTION based on the Sweeper answer, adding empty view, opacity and alignment

```
NavigationView {
            
            List {
                
                Section(header: Text("Available")) {
                    if classFromEntryPoint.availableApps.isEmpty {
                        Text("No app Available")
                    } else {
                        ForEach(classFromEntryPoint.availableApps) { app in
                            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                                    NavigationLink(destination: StoreAppDetailView(selectedApp: app)) { EmptyView() }
                                        .opacity(0.0)
                                    RowCell(app: app)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 17, you can use [`navigationDestination(item:destination:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationdestination(item:destination:)) to bind the navigation destination to a variable. That means you can just have `Button`s in your list, setting the variable to different values.

```
@State var tappedItem: FakeCar? = nil
```

```
NavigationStack { // this does not work with the old NavigationView!
    List {
        Section {
            ForEach(test) { item in
                Button {
                    self.tappedItem = item
                } label: {
                    Text(item.name)
                }
                .tint(.black)
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationDestination(item: $tappedItem) { item in
        Text("destination: \(item.name)")
    }
}
```

That said, this becomes rather cumbersome when you have multiple types of data (not just `FakeCar`s). You might need an enum with associated values, and switch on it in `navigationDestination` to compute what destination it should be.

As for the solution with the `ZStack`, you just need to say `alignment: .leading` for the alignment to work:

```
ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
    NavigationLink(destination: Text("destination: \(item.name)")) {
        EmptyView()
    }
    .opacity(0)
    Text(item.name)
}
```

Comment: added a structure with identifiable to question, I'll test your first proposal, but meanwhile, I added your second one and it is working, do not understand why ZStack did not accept the alignment initially, I had to paste your code.

Comment: @biggreentree Okay, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @biggreentree I forgot to mention that this works with a `NavigationStack`/`NavigationSplitView`, but not with the `NavigationView` that your code uses.

Comment: @Sweeper - why is `tappedItem` an optional?

Comment: @koen That's what `navigationDestination` takes. It will be set back to nil when you go back from the navigation destination.

Comment: @Sweeper as I said before your second bunch of advices worked for me, seems to be good. I will add the solution in the question as update, if you restore that part I can check your answer as solution.

Comment: @biggreentree Oh I misunderstood you before. I have updated the answer. Did I understand correctly? You shouldn't add the solution to the question though. That's what answers are for.

Comment: oh yes, it was a way to be clear with you in this case :D I'll remove it! immediately, I have another question connected with this mechanism here, you will fine again an answer in the question, but again, is there temporary. could you tell me if it is a good solution or I am "covering dust with carpet" ? thanks anyway!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77556578/swiftui-cannot-use-geometry-reader-to-make-look-good-a-cell-bot-in-portrait-and?noredirect=1#comment136727578_77556578