# swiftui cannot use geometry reader to make look good a cell bot in portrait and landscape on Avery device

Tags: list, swiftui, cell, geometryreader

Supporting iOS 15. With tis code I get a vertical cell with an image and a text, if there are notifications, I show a red round text. matter is on landscape my cell stretches too much, and notification is too far away. any solution I try if solves the iPad issue, maybe centers the red label instead putting it on right high corner.

- on iPhone 11 portrait - all ok
- on iPhone 11 landscape - notification set is a bit too distant
- on iPad  10th landscape notification is very far away

on iPhone portrait

[image: on iPhone portrait]

on iPad landscape

[image: on iPad landscape]

import SwiftUI

```
struct FavouritesWebAppsMainView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var classFromEntryPoint: ClassFromEntryPoint

    //code for presenting sheet.
    @State private var selectedItem: WebAppModel?
    //related to customized wkwebViews
    @State private var errorMessage: String = "none"
    @State private var showAlert = false
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            headerView
            mainBodyWithGrid
            .sheet(item: $selectedItem) { webApp in
                let test = webApp.appUrl
                if let url = URL(string: test) {
                    CustomWebView(url: url, messageErrorFromWebView: $errorMessage)
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            selectedItem = nil //Used to dismiss the sheet
                        }) {
                            Label("", systemImage: "xmark")
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                } else {
                    //never called
                    let _ = self.errorMessage = "Not valid URL"
                    let _ = self.showAlert = true
                    let _ = Logger.error("failed url: \(webApp.appUrl)")
                }
            }
        } //most external view
        .backgroundImage()

        .onChange(of: errorMessage, perform: { newValue in
            self.showAlert = true
        })
        .alert("Errore", isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Button("ok", role: .cancel) {}
        } message: {
            Text(self.errorMessage)
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: single views
    private var headerView: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Welvome")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
            }
            Text("Le tue app")
                .padding(.bottom)
        }
    }
    
    private var mainBodyWithGrid: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            ScrollView {
                if classFromEntryPoint.preferredAppList.isEmpty {
                    Text("Add App to the store")
                } else {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 30) {
                        ForEach(classFromEntryPoint.preferredAppList) { item in
                            VerticalCellView(item: item)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    self.selectedItem = item
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            }
            
            logoutButton
        }
    }
    
    private var logoutButton: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("Logout") {
                Logger.debug("logout")
                classFromEntryPoint.performLogout()
            }
            .padding()
            .background(.red)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            .padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }

    
}


//MARK: - cell

struct VerticalCellView: View {

    var item: WebAppModel

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack {
                    ImageDownloadedFromWeb(url: item.logoUrl ?? "N/D")
                        .frame(width: min(geometry.size.width, 100), height: min(geometry.size.width, 100))
                    Text(item.name)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    //                            Text(item.description)
                    //                                .font(.subheadline)
                    //                                .lineLimit(2)
                    //                                .truncationMode(.tail)
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
            }
            let notificationCount = (Int.random(in: 0...20))
            Text(notificationCount > 10 ? "99+" : "\(notificationCount)")
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                            .background(.red)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
        }
        .frame(height: 150)
    }
}
```

POSSIBLE SOLUTION but not clear why it is working

```
struct VerticalCellView: View {

    var item: WebAppModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ImageDownloadedFromWeb(url: item.logoUrl ?? "N/D")
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .overlay(
                    notificationBadge,
                    alignment: .topTrailing
                )
            Text(item.name)
                .font(.headline)
            //                            Text(item.description)
            //                                .font(.subheadline)
            //                                .lineLimit(2)
            //                                .truncationMode(.tail)
        }
        .frame(height: 150)
    }

    private var notificationBadge: some View {
        let notificationCount = (Int.random(in: 0...20))
        return Text(notificationCount > 10 ? "99+" : "\(notificationCount)")
            .font(.system(size: 12))
            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            .background(.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .offset(x: 10, y: -10)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest showing the badges as an overlay over the images, with alignment ```.topTrailing```. That way, they will never get detached.

Comment: new to swiftui, never used overlay, is there some con?

Comment: There are some limitations with overlays, but I wouldn't call them cons. The main thing to be aware of is that an overlay is constrained by the frame of the view it is applied to. It's like a mini ```ZStack``` with the size determined by the base view. So as long as the overlay does not need to be larger than the underlying view, this works fine. If you need to break out of the bounds of the frame then it may not be the best solution (a real ```ZStack``` might be better), but that is not the case here. Btw, a background layer works similarly.

Comment: I tried a bit more with overlay, it seems to be working, but it is not clear to me why, could you help me understand what is happening?

Comment: I read your reply too quickly and thought you were saying it didn't work, so I added a full answer to illustrate. The reason the overlay stays with the image is because the overlay has the same constraining frame as the image, as I was trying to explain above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up on the comments, I would suggest showing the badges as an overlay over the images. This way, the badges will never be detached from the images.

Here is a stripped-down version of your example to illustrate how you can do it with overlays. In the spirit of a *minimal reproducible example* I left out everything that wasn't needed or relevant. In particular, I found myself wondering, why you were using a `GeometryReader` at all? The size it was giving you was the size of the grid cell, but this is not particularly useful. So I think it can be solved without using a `GeometryReader`.

```swift
struct WebAppModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let logo: String
    let name: String
}

struct FavouritesWebAppsMainView: View {

    let items: [WebAppModel] = [
        WebAppModel(logo: "lizard", name: "test1"),
        WebAppModel(logo: "ant", name: "test2"),
        WebAppModel(logo: "tortoise", name: "test3"),
        WebAppModel(logo: "fossil.shell", name: "test4"),
    ]

    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        mainBodyWithGrid
    }

    private var mainBodyWithGrid: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 30) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    VerticalCellView(item: item)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}

struct VerticalCellView: View {

    var item: WebAppModel

    private var randomNotificationBadge: some View {
        let notificationCount = (Int.random(in: 0...20))
        return Text(notificationCount > 10 ? "99+" : "\(notificationCount)")
            .font(.system(size: 12))
            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            .background(.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(Circle())
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: item.logo)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(.yellow.opacity(0.2))
                .overlay(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                    randomNotificationBadge
                }
            Text(item.name)
                .font(.headline)
        }
        .frame(height: 150)
    }
}
```

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

The screenshots are from an iPad 10th gen.

Comment: I was using geometry reader as I don before with things such self.view.frame. etc. I still have doubt about the frame fixed to 150. example: your solution gives me cells of different sizes, (I think due to image sizes)is it good to give them a fixed frame? I thought give them a dynamic size could be better. That's why I include everything inside the code since I am not sure what is conflicting with what else. thanks for your help anyway.